# How do I install an old version of Firefox (3.6) on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I need Firefox 3.6 for a website that only allows Firefox 3.x or IE 8.0 or below.  I have uninstalled the current version of Firefox on Ubuntu and have downloaded the correct installer, but there are no instructions for installing it.

Answer (score 3):

If its a `tar.gz` you need to expand it with `tar -xf` and run it from in there (or copy it to `/usr/local`).

There may be a `README` file there with details. If its a `.deb`, you can install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i (packagename).deb
```

or double clicking on it

Comment: The tar.gz file for 3.6.25 on https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html contains a README which only refers to the web site (a non-existing page there), and the `firefox` binary there doesn't start (`error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`) on a current Ubuntu.

Comment: Its an old question with insufficient information - your issue may be different. From your error, it looks like you're lacking a prerequisite - try installing libgtk-x11 from your package manager and see if it works

Comment: Current Ubuntu doesn't provide this package (at least, not under this name). I solved the original problem by managing to instruct my package manager to install the package from an older Ubuntu (Maverick), and it then actually showed I didn't even need an old Firefox (as we found a GWT development plugin for Firefox 9). Still, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it the [official web site](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html) or [here](http://www.oldapps.com/linux/firefox.php)

EDIT : 'here' link updated

Comment: Your "here" download offers only Windows versions.